# How to change part of string in R

Tags: r, string, replace, statistics, grepl

I have a question regarding string manipulation in R. I have a data frame with two columns:

```
NAME          DATE
xxx-test-xx   2015-02-03
Frank         2015-02-01
Steve         2014-09-31
132-test-ggg  2012-12-09
```

I want to change all cases in column *NAME* which contains word "test" into one name - for example "TEST". I have prepared code as below but it doesn't work - appropriate cases are not found as they should be. Observations in NAME variable do not have any particular pattern. Could you tell me how to fix it?

```
dataset$EMAIL <- as.character(dataset$EMAIL) 

for (i in 1:length(dataset)) {
  if(grepl("test", dataset$EMAIL[i], ignore.case=TRUE))  {
    dataset$EMAIL[i] <- "TEST"
  }
}
```

Comment: Whatever the solution is (the two provided look good) do not forget to set `stringsAsFactors = F` when import data, otherwise (not all)  provided solutions will cause troubles.

Answer (score 6):

When you do `length(dataset)` you will return the number of columns in your dataframe, not the number of rows. To fix your loop, you can do `1:nrow(dataset)`. But actually you can get rid of the `for` loop entirely in this case and do

```
dataset$EMAIL <- as.character(dataset$EMAIL) 
dataset$EMAIL[grepl("test", dataset$EMAIL, ignore.case=T)] <- "TEST"
```

Answer (score 4):

First things first, you do not need to loop over all entries in the column you can rely on `R` being vectorized.

Then you could simply use `gsub`

```
gsub(".*test.*", "TEST", dataset$EMAIL)
```